# Convergence of a recursively defined sequence for certain initial values

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am working on a problem where we are given a function $f'(x)$ continuous on the Real Numbers. We are told $f(a)=a$, and $|f'(a)|<1$. We define a sequence of numbers by: given any $x_0$, $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. We now wish to show that for $x_0$ sufficiently close to a, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=a$. I am having a difficult time interpreting what it means to say $x_0$ sufficiently close to a. I would assume this means $x_0 \in [a-\delta,a+\delta]$, but this tells me nothing about delta, and dead ends very quickly.

I am not looking for the full solution, just an explanation on what it means in this case to say $x_0$ is sufficiently close to a.

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. The sequence isn't guaranteed to converge to $a$ for every initial state, but you are guaranteed that $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. if $x_0 \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$ the sequence converges to $a$, i.e. $a$ is a stable fixed point of the system.

Comment: Yes, "sufficiently close" means $\lvert x-a\rvert \leqslant \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. Part of your task is to find [well, prove the existence of] such a $\delta$. Look at the definition of $f'(a)$ [Note that it is not assumed that $f$ is differentiable in any other point than $a$] to get the existence of such a $\delta$.

Comment: That was my mistake, f'(x) is supposed to be continuous over the reals.